# Cut and tr: command not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Whats wrong whit this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin

. /lib/init/vars.sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

 HOSTNAME="TAI-$(ifconfig | grep "HWaddr" | cut -d" " -f11 | tr -s ":" "-")"
```

Then:

```
root@teste:/ ./hostname.sh <enter>
```

The script return:

```
./hostname.sh: 7: ./hostname.sh: cut: not found
./hostname.sh: 7: ./hostname.sh: tr: not found
```

But in console (command line) run perfect.

```
root@teste:/ HOSTNAME="TAI-$(ifconfig | grep "HWaddr" | cut -d" " -f11 | tr -s ":" "-")" <enter>

root@teste:/ echo $HOSTNAME <enter>
root@teste:/ TAI-b8-27-eb-81-4f-c5  - It's OK.
```

Someone could help me please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the line:

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin
```

`cut` and `tr` are in `/usr/bin` , which is missing from your `PATH`. Add `:/usr/bin` to the end of the `PATH`  variable.

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

Comment: make sure there is no space in PATH=/sbin

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain Either that, or if there are directories with spaces in their names, make sure to always quote everything that comes from a variable, such as "$@", "$PATH", etc. Anyway, it is a good practice to quote everything and even test with filenames/directories that contain spaces.

I did not quote my answer, since does not contain spaces and does not depend on variables/output results that may contain spaces.